# How do we evaluate the joint distribution and expectation of three uniform dependent random variables?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Before I begin, I wanted to say I have gone through the following links which touch on this topic. 
1. [Link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308859/joint-density-of-dependent-random-variables/2308902)
2. [Link2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215888/joint-distribution-of-two-dependent-random-variables)
3. [Link3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308859/joint-density-of-dependent-random-variables?rq=1)
4. [Link4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308859/joint-density-of-dependent-random-variables)
and what I understand is that joint density for dependent variables do not exist as it has zero Lebesgue measure. Is my understanding correct? If yes, can we find the expected value?

Let us consider 3 Random Variables $X$~$U(10,20)$, $Y$~$U(20,40)$ and $Z$~$U(20,70)$ which are related as $X+Y+Z=60$. Is there a way we can write the expectation and if we can, what does it intuitively mean?

Edit: Correcting mistake in initial question where $Z$~$U(40,60)$ which was wrong and as correctly pointed out by ClementC.

Comment: The expected value of *what*, exactly? All three of them, separately? (if that's what you're asking... yes) Or the expectation of the vector? (which... [well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_random_variable#Expected_value), is related to the first thing)

Comment: ...all three of them separately, I mean!

Comment: Then you have no problem at all. $\mathbb{E}[X] = 15$, $\mathbb{E}[Y] = 30$, $\mathbb{E}[Z] = 50$ — the fact that $X,Y,Z$ are dependent does know change the expectation of $X$. The expectation $\mathbb{E}[X]$ does not change if I am aware that there exists a r.v. $X'$ which is not independent of $X$.

Comment: Now, however, in your **specific** case you may have a problem, since with what you have written there is no way that a triple $(X,Y,Z)$ like that can **exist**. You can't have $X\geq 10$ a.s., $Y\geq 20$ a.s., and $Z\geq 40$ a.s. summing a.s. to $50 < 10+20+40$.

Comment: (Even with the current change. You have $\mathbb{E}[X+Y+Z] = \mathbb{E}[X]+\mathbb{E}[Y]+\mathbb{E}[Z]$ (when all is well-defined, and here they are) regardless of dependence, and here that's equal to $15+30+45=90$. But the "relation" would impose $90=50$. Are you sure this comes from a real scenario, and that there is no typo?)

Comment: i have edited the question, thanks for pointing out. Also, what I understand from your explanation is that dependence between r.v does not change the expected values. Is there a proof for it? What i still cannot make intuitive sense is that why does the sum constrain not affect the expectation? I think I am missing something basic.

Comment: See e.g., https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/

Comment: thank you for this.